# Magento : Need Datepicker Frontend Form

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, frontend, calendar

I have recently set magento default datepicker at frontend but its not work. I add required file using xml like this,

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!--
    Default layout, loads most of the pages
    -->

    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">

            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>

                <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

                <!-- Remove items which the RWD package is not dependent upoTypeError: this.each is not a functionn -->
                <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name></action>

                <!-- Add vendor dependencies -->
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/modernizr.custom.min.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/selectivizr.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/matchMedia.addListener.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/enquire.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/app.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.min.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/slideshow.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/imagesloaded.js</name></action>
                <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,700,600</href></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/minicart.js</name></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params></params></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><params></params></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><params></params></action>
                <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>

                <!-- Add stylesheets with no media queries for use in IE 8 and below -->
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie8.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[ (lte IE 8) & (!IEMobile)]]></if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/madisonisland-ie8.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[ (lte IE 8) & (!IEMobile)]]></if></action>

                <!-- Add stylesheets with media queries for use by modern browsers -->
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/madisonisland.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>

                <!-- Sets viewport meta tag using text block -->
                <block type="core/text" name="head.viewport">
                    <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />]]>&#10;</text></action>
                </block>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start" translate="label">
                <label>Page Top</label>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_notices" name="global_notices" as="global_notices" template="page/html/notices.phtml" />

            <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
                <block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="top.container" as="topContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Header</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>top-container</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="left_first" as="left_first" translate="label">
                <label>Left Column First (shows above main column on smaller screens)</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="left" as="left" translate="label">
                <label>Left Column</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
            <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
                <label>Main Content Area</label>
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
                <label>Right Column</label>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="footer.before" as="footer_before" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>footer-before-container</value></action>
            </block>

            <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Footer</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="*" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle"><title>Quick Links</title></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links2" as="footer_links2" template="page/template/links.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle"><title>Account</title></action>
                </block>
                <!-- This static block can be created and populated in admin. The footer_links cms block can be used as a starting point. -->
                <!--<block type="cms/block" name="footer_social_links">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_social_links</block_id></action>
                </block>-->
            </block>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
                <label>Page Bottom</label>
                <block type="page/html_cookieNotice" name="global_cookie_notice" as ="global_cookie_notice" template="page/html/cookienotice.phtml" before="-" />
            </block>
        </block>

        <block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
    </default>
```

Form.phtml

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add', array('product'=>$_product->getId(),'qty'=>1, 'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>" method="post" name="headstone-product-form" id="headstone-product-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <?php /* catagory Block start */ ?>
        <div class="headstone-tab-block" >
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $productId; ?>" name="productName" id="productName" />
            <div class="headstone-tab" id="memorial-category"><span> MEMORAIL CATEGORY </span></div>
                <?php  if(!empty($images)){
                        foreach($images as $image){
                        $imageData = $image->getData(); 

                ?>
            ata-name="<?php echo $imageData['category_name']; ?>" id="headstone-category-<?php echo $imageData['category_name']; ?>" value=" <?php echo $imageData['category_id']; ?>" /> <label for="headstone-category-<?php echo $imageData['category_name']; ?>" ><?php echo $imageData['category_name']; ?></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php } } ?>
        </div>
        <?php /* catagory Block end */ ?>

        <?php /* Type, style, size Block Start */ ?>
        <div class="headstone-tab-block" >
            <div class="headstone-tab" id="memorial-type"><span>SELECT MEMORAIL TYPE AND SIZE </span></div>
                <div class="memorial-block" id="memorial-block-type">
                    <div class="headstone-style" id="ajax-style-fillup">
                            <?php /* full data using ajax */ ?>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="headstone-type" id="ajax-type-fillup">
                            <?php /* full data using ajax */ ?>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="headstone-type" id="size-ajax-fillup">
                            <?php /* fill up using ajax */ ?>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="stonePrice" id="stonePrice" value="<?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="finalPrice" id="finalPrice" value="<?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?>" />
                    <div class="price-info" id="price-info"><?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?></div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <?php /* Type, style, size Block end */ ?>

        <?php /* Color, Pattern Block start */ ?>
        <div class="headstone-tab-block" >
            <div class="headstone-tab" id="memorial-color"><span>SELECT COLOR AND DESIGN </span></div>
                <div class="memorial-block" id="memorial-block-color">
                    <div class="headstone-color" id="headstone-ajax-color">
                        <?php /* fill color using ajax */ ?>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="headstone-pannel" id="headstone-ajax-pannel">
                        <?php /* fill pannel using ajax */ ?>
                    </div>      
                </div>
        </div>
        <?php /* Color, Pattern Block end */ ?>

        <div class="headstone-result hidden">
            <div class="headstone-result-head">
                <h3 id="headstone-result-title"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="headstone-result-parent hidden" id="result-block-single">
                <div class="headstone-category-result">
                    <div class="headstone-color-result" id="headstone-color-result">
                        <div class="headstone-pannel-result">
                            <!-- <div class="left-image" id="left-image"></div> -->
                            <div class="right-image" id="right-image"></div>
                            <input type="file" name="leftImageName" id="leftImageName" class="hidden" />
                            <input type="file" name="rightImageName" id="rightImageName" class="hidden" />
                            <div class="result-name">
                                <input type="text" class="name required-entry" name="name" id="name" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="result-bod">
                                <input type="text" class="bod required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-from" name="bod" id="bod" value="" />
                                <img title="Select date"  id="bod_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif')?>" class="v-middle img-bod">
                            </div>
                            <div class="result-expire-date">
                                <input type="text" class="expire-date required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-to" name="expire-date" id="expire-date" value="" />
                                <img title="Select date" id="expire_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif')?>" class="v-middle img-bod">
                            </div>
                            <div class="result-about-person">
                                <input type="text" class="result-about required-entry" name="result-about" id="result-about" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" class="result-div" name="result_image" id="result_image" value="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="headstone-result-couple hidden" id="result-block-couple">
                <div class="headstone-category-couple">
                    <div class="headstone-color-couple" id="headstone-color-couple">
                        <div class="headstone-pannel-couple" id="headstone-pannel-couple">
                            <div class="left-image-couple" id="left-image-couple"></div>
                            <div class="right-image-couple" id="right-image-couple"></div>
                            <input type="file" name="leftImageNameCouple" id="leftImageNameCouple" class="hidden" />
                            <input type="file" name="rightImageNameCouple" id="rightImageNameCouple" class="hidden" />
                            <div class="result-namecouple">
                                <input type="text" class="namecouple required-entry" name="name" id="nameCouple" value="" />
                                <input type="text" class="namecouple required-entry" name="wifeNameCouple" id="wifeNameCouple" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="result-bodcouple">
                                <span class="left-couple-date">
                                    <input type="text" class="bodcouple required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-from" name="bod" id="bodCouple" value="" />
                                    <img title="Select date" id="bodCouple_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif')?>" class="v-middle img-bod">
                                </span>
                                <span class="right-couple-date">
                                    <input type="text" class="bodcouple required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-from" name="wifeBodCouple" id="wifeBodCouple" value="" />
                                    <img title="Select date" id="wifeBodCouple_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif')?>" class="v-middle img-bod">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="result-expire-datecouple">
                                <span class="left-couple-date">
                                    <input type="text" class="expire-datecouple required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-to" name="expire-date" id="expire-date-couple" value="" />
                                    <img title="Select date" id="expire-date-couple_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif')?>" class="v-middle img-bod">
                                </span>
                                <span class="right-couple-date">
                                    <input type="text" class="expire-datecouple required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-to" name="wifeExpire-date-couple" id="wifeExpire-date-couple" value="" />
                                    <img title="Select date" id="wifeExpire_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif')?>" class="v-middle img-bod">
                                </span> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="result-about-personcouple">
                                <input type="text" class="result-aboutcouple required-entry" name="result-aboutCouple" id="result-aboutCouple" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" class="result-div" name="result_image_couple" id="result_image_couple" value="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $buttonTitle = Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')); ?>
            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <div class="price-info" id="price-info-bottom"> <?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?>  </div>
                <div class="add-to-cart">
                    <div class="add-to-cart-buttons">
                        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart"  ><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </form>     <div class="memorial-block" id="headstone-category">
                        <div class="headstone-category-image">
                            <image src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$imageData['category_image']; ?>" />
                            <input type="radio" name="headstone-category"  data-image="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$imageData['category_image'];  ?>" data-name="<?php echo $imageData['category_name']; ?>" id="headstone-category-<?php echo $imageData['category_name']; ?>" value=" <?php echo $imageData['category_id']; ?>" /> <label for="headstone-category-<?php echo $imageData['category_name']; ?>" ><?php echo $imageData['category_name']; ?></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php } } ?>
        </div>
        <?php /* catagory Block end */ ?>

        <?php /* Type, style, size Block Start */ ?>
        <div class="headstone-tab-block" >
            <div class="headstone-tab" id="memorial-type"><span>SELECT MEMORAIL TYPE AND SIZE </span></div>
                <div class="memorial-block" id="memorial-block-type">
                    <div class="headstone-style" id="ajax-style-fillup">
                            <?php /* full data using ajax */ ?>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="headstone-type" id="ajax-type-fillup">
                            <?php /* full data using ajax */ ?>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="headstone-type" id="size-ajax-fillup">
                            <?php /* fill up using ajax */ ?>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="stonePrice" id="stonePrice" value="<?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="finalPrice" id="finalPrice" value="<?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?>" />
                    <div class="price-info" id="price-info"><?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?></div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <?php /* Type, style, size Block end */ ?>

        <?php /* Color, Pattern Block start */ ?>
        <div class="headstone-tab-block" >
            <div class="headstone-tab" id="memorial-color"><span>SELECT COLOR AND DESIGN </span></div>
                <div class="memorial-block" id="memorial-block-color">
                    <div class="headstone-color" id="headstone-ajax-color">
                        <?php /* fill color using ajax */ ?>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="headstone-pannel" id="headstone-ajax-pannel">
                        <?php /* fill pannel using ajax */ ?>
                    </div>      
                </div>
        </div>
        <?php /* Color, Pattern Block end */ ?>

        <div class="headstone-result hidden">
            <div class="headstone-result-head">
                <h3 id="headstone-result-title"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="headstone-result-parent hidden" id="result-block-single">
                <div class="headstone-category-result">
                    <div class="headstone-color-result" id="headstone-color-result">
                        <div class="headstone-pannel-result">
                            <!-- <div class="left-image" id="left-image"></div> -->
                            <div class="right-image" id="right-image"></div>
                            <input type="file" name="leftImageName" id="leftImageName" class="hidden" />
                            <input type="file" name="rightImageName" id="rightImageName" class="hidden" />
                            <div class="result-name">
                                <input type="text" class="name required-entry" name="name" id="name" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="result-bod">
                                <input type="text" class="bod required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-from" name="bod" id="bod" value="" />
                                <img title="Select date"  id="bod_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif')?>" class="v-middle img-bod">
                            </div>
                            <div class="result-expire-date">
                                <input type="text" class="expire-date required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-to" name="expire-date" id="expire-date" value="" />
                                <img title="Select date" id="expire_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif')?>" class="v-middle img-bod">
                            </div>
                            <div class="result-about-person">
                                <input type="text" class="result-about required-entry" name="result-about" id="result-about" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" class="result-div" name="result_image" id="result_image" value="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="headstone-result-couple hidden" id="result-block-couple">
                <div class="headstone-category-couple">
                    <div class="headstone-color-couple" id="headstone-color-couple">
                        <div class="headstone-pannel-couple" id="headstone-pannel-couple">
                            <div class="left-image-couple" id="left-image-couple"></div>
                            <div class="right-image-couple" id="right-image-couple"></div>
                            <input type="file" name="leftImageNameCouple" id="leftImageNameCouple" class="hidden" />
                            <input type="file" name="rightImageNameCouple" id="rightImageNameCouple" class="hidden" />
                            <div class="result-namecouple">
                                <input type="text" class="namecouple required-entry" name="name" id="nameCouple" value="" />
                                <input type="text" class="namecouple required-entry" name="wifeNameCouple" id="wifeNameCouple" value="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="result-bodcouple">
                                <span class="left-couple-date">
                                    <input type="text" class="bodcouple required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-from" name="bod" id="bodCouple" value="" />
                                    <img title="Select date" id="bodCouple_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif')?>" class="v-middle img-bod">
                                </span>
                                <span class="right-couple-date">
                                    <input type="text" class="bodcouple required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-from" name="wifeBodCouple" id="wifeBodCouple" value="" />
                                    <img title="Select date" id="wifeBodCouple_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif')?>" class="v-middle img-bod">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="result-expire-datecouple">
                                <span class="left-couple-date">
                                    <input type="text" class="expire-datecouple required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-to" name="expire-date" id="expire-date-couple" value="" />
                                    <img title="Select date" id="expire-date-couple_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif')?>" class="v-middle img-bod">
                                </span>
                                <span class="right-couple-date">
                                    <input type="text" class="expire-datecouple required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-to" name="wifeExpire-date-couple" id="wifeExpire-date-couple" value="" />
                                    <img title="Select date" id="wifeExpire_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif')?>" class="v-middle img-bod">
                                </span> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="result-about-personcouple">
                                <input type="text" class="result-aboutcouple required-entry" name="result-aboutCouple" id="result-aboutCouple" value="" />
                                <input type="hidden" class="result-div" name="result_image_couple" id="result_image_couple" value="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $buttonTitle = Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')); ?>
            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <div class="price-info" id="price-info-bottom"> <?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?>  </div>
                <div class="add-to-cart">
                    <div class="add-to-cart-buttons">
                        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart"  ><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </form>
```

My Script.

```
Calendar.setup({
        inputField : "bodCouple",
        ifFormat : "%e/%m/%y",
        button : "bodCouple_trig",
        showsTime: false,
        align : "Bl",
        singleClick : true
});
```

I don't know what is issue with this.

Comment: Any console error in frontend?

Comment: No. error on frontend

Answer (score 1):

You need to add following file in your page using xml.

```
<action method=”addItem”><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params></params></action>
<action method=”addItem”><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name></action>
<action method=”addItem”><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name></action>
```

Add following code in your `Form.phtml` file.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_calendar')->setTemplate('page/js/calendar.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

<span class="left-couple-date">
     <input type="text" class="bodcouple required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-from" name="bodCouple" id="bodCouple" value="" />
     <img title="Select date" id="bodCouple_trig" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif')?>" class="v-middle img-bod">
</span>

Calendar.setup({
        inputField : "bodCouple",
        ifFormat : "%e/%m/%y",
        button : "bodCouple_trig",
        showsTime: false,
        align : "Bl",
        singleClick : true
});
```

Comment: I have try this but no luck

Comment: can you share complete code of your xml and form.phtml file.

Comment: check updated question

Comment: update answer, please check.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya How can i do, the customer chooses the date on PDP page. It is necessary field customer need to choose which date your products want to deliver. How can i add the calendar on PDP Page?